# MySQL/PHP Autosuggest

Tags: mysql, character, cpu-word, code-first, autosuggest

In my MySQL DB I have a list of terms like this (With First letters Capital and most of the time plurals)

```
Hairdressers
Restaurants
Beauty Salons 
Furnitures For Restaurants
```

On my website I have a search bar where the user can search for those word (my website is a kind of POI finder). The search bar has a auto-suggest function, but I'm having problems with my query.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE word = 'userword%'
```

So if the user enter "Res" it will return all the word starting the "Res". Fair enough, that works, But in my DB i have also words with space between them (Furnitures For Restaurants) and I would like that if the user enter "Res" the mysql query ALSO return Furnitures For Restaurants. I have tried this

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE word = '%userword%'
```

Yes great this works, but... it is a bit to much relax.. it return all and everything, so if the user enters "a" it will return all the word having a in it... And I don't want this.

So how can make the query works only on the FIRST letters of each word ? Exactly like my first query but taking in consideration words with spaces?

Comment: You probably want to pass a regexp to mysql. Sorry but dont have time to post a full answer :-(

Comment: Full text is the way to go. A regexp will work too, but if you really only want the two cases you are stating, an OR might work as well: `WHERE word LIKE 'userword%' OR word like '% userword%'` (notice the space before the userword in the second query).

Comment: That doesn't work if userword = restaurant (without s) the query returns Fournitures for Restaurant first and then restaurants

Answer (score 0):

Look into mysql [FULL Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html) feature. Look at this [article](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1304) too, explains mysql full text searching in a very detailed way.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the hint, I didn't know about FULLtext search. So i did a test but there seem that the search engine doesn't work with pural/singular. for example if a do a match(name) agains('restaurant') it return 0 rows.. but if I add a 's' it return me the right row.. I tried in boolean mode bit it seems that the score system doesn't work ??mysql> select *, MATCH(name) AGAINST ('restaurant*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS s
core from activites where match(nom) AGAINST('restaurant*' IN BOOLEAN M
ODE) ORDER BY score DESC; All the score are 0

Comment: Full text search work on data across rows. Search generally improves if you have several rows. It treats a word as spam, if it occurs in around say 50% of rows and won't show rows containing that word.